# Assign a function to a variable with conditional (ruby)

Tags: ruby

Well I have a `question` object that as you can see it receives parameters `true / false`, what I would like is that in the variable `question_type` given the value of `questions[:q1]` it is assigned one of the functions `question_type_true` or `question_type_false` to be able to execute it within the each.

```
questions = {
  q1: true,
  q3: true,
  q4: true,
  q5: true,
  q6: true,
  q7: true,
  q8: true
}

question_type = questions[:q1] == true ? question_type_true : question_type_false

questions.each do |key, value|
  question_type(value)
end


def question_type_true(question)
  p "true function #{question}"
end

def question_type_false(question)
  p "false function #{question}"
end
```

example:

```
questions = { q1: false, q3: true, q4: true}
```

output:

```
p "true function false"
p "true function true"
p "true function true
```

Comment: Your output does not match your code? the example shows `questions[:q1] == false` which would result in the usage of the `question_type_false` method not the `question_type_true` method as your output suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just store the name of the method as a symbol

```
question_type = questions[:q1] ? :question_type_true : :question_type_false
```

Then [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) the symbol to the object you want the method to run on:

```
questions.each do |key, value|
  send question_type, value
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) to get a reference to a [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) and then [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call) it:

```
question_type = questions[:q1] == true ? method(:question_type_true) : method(:question_type_false)

questions.each do |key, value|
  question_type.call(value)
end
```

Note that you will need to have defined the methods before you can call `method` to retrieve it:

```
# works:
def some_method; end
method(:some_method)

# undefined method error:
method(:some_method)
def some_method; end
```

so you'll need to move your method definitions to the top of the example given.

If the method you need is an instance method on something, you can access it by calling `method` on the instance:

```
o = Object.new
o.method(:nil?)
```

and similarly if it's a class method:

```
Object.method(:new)
```